# IE 10 open tabs AND PDFs

Tags: pdf, windows-7, registry, internet-explorer-10

I am having a lot of issues with IE 10, the first issue I had was that IE10 did not want to open links in new tabs. I found the solution to this by creating the registry entry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/TabProcGrowth with a value of 0
```

Some people said that it should be a 1 but, for me only 0 fixed the new tab issue. Next, opening a PDF... when trying to open PDFs all I get is a small black box with an X in it. I researched this issue and everywhere I found it said that the solution is to create:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/TabProcGrowth with a value of 1
```

So, I changed it to 1 and sure enough PDFs are working now, but now the new tab doesn't work.

So the question is:
What am I missing? I need both of these features to work. Has anybody else encountered this issue.

This is IE10 on Windows 7.

**UPDATE**

So, We had no other choice so we called Microsoft. I got somewhat of a solution for this but it is still not resolved 100%. Apparently you don't need the above registry entry at all. The preliminary solution that has been given is:

> Open regedit and go to the below registry,
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{79EAC9C5-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B}\ProxyStubClsid32
>
> The problematic value: {79EAC9D0-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B}
>
> The correct value: {A4A1A128-768F-41E0-BF75-E4FDDD701CBA}

Also get rid of the TabProcGrowth registry entry. This resolved opening new tabs and opening PDF "FILES". That means that if you are trying to open "test.pdf" it will work like a champ. If you are clicking on a link that sends you to a service, servlet or anything else that dynamically renders a pdf using the content type "application/pdf" it wont render at all.

I am still working with them and will update as soon as I get this resolved.

**NEW UPDATE**

Just to give everyone an update on this issue. We continue to experience this issue with all new computers we setup here in our office. We have had to adjust the registry every time. We  recently took the time and took the new computer setup one step at a time to see what part of our setup messes with the registry. At the end we found that we are installing a product called **Imaging Professional**, right after this install the registry got messed up again.

We unfortunately were installing this, because some of our older software uses it. We are currently working on the new enhanced version of that application and will no longer need to install Imaging Professional anymore.

FYI, even if you remove it your registry will still be messed up. Manual fix must be applied.

Comment: I don't have that registry entry here, and IE10 will open links in new tabs (either by user command or by having a "_blank" target) and PDF files just fine. How about completely offing that entry?

Comment: I had tried that to, when I remove it the PDFs work fine but the tabs don't work. All of the Windows 7 boxes here in the office had the 'New Tab' issue until we created that entry, but now its the PDF issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Renan I was re-reading the path of the registry and it seemed I for got the Internet Explorer folder in there. That's where the Main folder is. Can you please check to see if you have it?

Comment: Checked. I don't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question and to let everyone know. The fix that was given by Microsoft in fact does work. The only thing that is missing from the instructions is to restart Windows.

So the complete solution:

> Open regedit and go to the below registry,
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface{79EAC9C5-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B}\ProxyStubClsid32
>
> The problematic value: {79EAC9D0-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B} (or any other value other than the correct one)
>
> The correct value: {A4A1A128-768F-41E0-BF75-E4FDDD701CBA}
>
> Delete/Remove the registry entry TabProcGrowth
>
> RESTART your PC!

Hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

No, deleting `TabProcGrowth` and setting value: `{A4A1A128-768F-41E0-BF75-E4FDDD701CBA}` doesn't solve the issue.

So I repeat again:

`CTRL+click` or middle button or right click to open in tab - doesn't work in `IE10 Win7`. 
But drag and drop link on the TAB is working!!! :-) 
This happens if user is not an administrator. Log in as admin on the same machine resolves the problem.

Comment: Hey Dronus, if you still haven't fixed it try this. Get into the registry editor and click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, do a CTRL-F and search for 79EAC9C5-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B it will be multiple times in different folders, one of them will be wrong.